# The \usepackage[T4]{fontenc} is making my text so strange

Tags: overleaf

Can someone help me? I just need this package to use some "cutted d (derivatives)" in the thermodynamics parts.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you please upload a higher-resolution version of the page in question? Also, for the benefit of readers who aren't intimately familiar with thermodynamics notation, would you mind stating where on the page the relevant glyphs occur? Finally, do please state *how* you enable/activate T4 font encoding. Does the preamble feature the instruction `\usepackage[T4,T1]{fontenc}`, or is it just `\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}`? (Hint: the former is probably what you want.)

Comment: This is the resolution. That's why I'm telling you that I have a problem. :/
Looks like I'm using a low ink printer.

Comment: Please also tell us how exactly you enable the T4 font encoding?

Comment: Using `T4` almost surely uses bitmap fonts. Use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, that also provides the barred d (notwithstanding the fact that IMO people who use that notation do not really understand thermodynamics `;-)`).